# Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException' exception

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 models in my application which have the one-to-many and many-to-one relationships.

The model classes are:

**Invoice Model**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Invoice implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    private String business;

    private String client;

    private String invoiceNo;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private InvoiceStatus status;

    private String additionalInfo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice")
    private Set<InvoiceItem> items = new HashSet<>();

    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    private LocalDateTime deletedAt;
}
```

**InvoiceItem Model**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class InvoiceItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="invoice_id", nullable = false)
    private Invoice invoice;

    private String description;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private InvoiceItemType type;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    private LocalDateTime deletedAt;
}
```

I have an api endpoint which is used to create an invoiceItem for an invoice

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/api/v1/invoices/{invoice}/items")
public class InvoiceItemController {

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    private InvoiceItemService invoiceItemService;

    @Autowired
    private InvoiceService invoiceService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<InvoiceItem> addInvoiceItem(@PathVariable("invoice") String invoiceId, @RequestBody InvoiceItemCreationDto invoiceItemCreationDto) throws NotFoundException {

        Optional<Invoice> invoiceOptional = invoiceService.findInvoiceById(invoiceId);

        if (!invoiceOptional.isPresent()) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Invoice not found");
        }

        InvoiceItem invoiceItem = modelMapper.map(invoiceItemCreationDto, InvoiceItem.class);
        invoiceItem.setInvoice(invoiceOptional.get());

        InvoiceItem savedInvoiceItem = invoiceItemService.addInvoiceItem(invoiceItem);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedInvoiceItem, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

**Invoice Service**

```
package com.spencerfeng.invoiceservice.services;

import com.spencerfeng.invoiceservice.models.Invoice;
import com.spencerfeng.invoiceservice.repositories.InvoiceRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.Optional;

public class InvoiceServiceImpl implements InvoiceService {
    @Autowired
    InvoiceRepository invoiceRepository;

    @Override
    public Invoice addInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
        return invoiceRepository.save(invoice);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Invoice> findInvoiceById(String id) {
        return invoiceRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

**Invoice Repository**

```
package com.spencerfeng.invoiceservice.repositories;

import com.spencerfeng.invoiceservice.models.Invoice;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface InvoiceRepository extends CrudRepository<Invoice, String> {
}
```

**InvoiceItem Service**

```
package com.spencerfeng.invoiceservice.services;

import com.spencerfeng.invoiceservice.models.InvoiceItem;
import com.spencerfeng.invoiceservice.repositories.InvoiceItemRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class InvoiceItemServiceImpl implements InvoiceItemService {
    @Autowired
    private InvoiceItemRepository invoiceItemRepository;

    @Override
    public InvoiceItem addInvoiceItem(InvoiceItem invoiceItem) {
        return invoiceItemRepository.save(invoiceItem);
    }
}
```

But when I call this api endpoint to create an invoiceItem for an invoice, the items property in the invoiceOptional has the 'Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException' exception, while other properties are fine.

[image: The screenshot of the issue]

[image]

Comment: Hello @spencerfeng , can u make show sql =true and check what sql is getting generated ?

Comment: Also add the code invoiceService in the question

Comment: @MandarDharurkar Thank you, I have added all the details in.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related bnut that StackOverflowError in `Invoice.toString()` might be something to look into. If it's have to guess I'd assume it's the Invoice <-> InvoiceItem relation.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you, I guess so. Do you know what is the general solution to this? Do I need to write a custom toString() method for Invoice model or something else?

Comment: @spencerfeng if you execute this auto generated sql directly in DB console , is it returning correct response ? if yes , then problem might be in toString method , if no then problem is in mappinfg itself

Comment: Well that `@Data` indicates you're using Lombok or something like that so you'd have to have a look into how this generates `toString()` (or maybe it's just your IDE that's trying to be clever here).

Comment: Another thing to look out for would be circular dependencies between invoice and items during json serialization. However the exception you'd get in that case (assuming you didn't replace Jackson with something else) should be quite clear about that if it happens.

Comment: "I have added all the details in." - unfortunately there are still things that are missing, e.g. what's actually happening here: `invoiceItemService.addInvoiceItem(invoiceItem);`.

Comment: yes @Thomas is right , can you please add details about invoiceItemService.addInvoiceItem(invoiceItem); method

Comment: Hi @Thomas, thank you for your help. It is caused by circular toString\hashcode reference.

Comment: Hi @MandarDharurkar, thank you for your help. It is caused by circular toString\hashcode reference.

Comment: @spencerfeng great !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try to exclude the circular tostring\hashcode reference on one POJO:

```
@ToString(exclude = "invoice")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "invoice")
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
public class InvoiceItem {
```

or to do it by using @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude & @ToString.Exclude on the field

```
@Entity
@Data
public class InvoiceItem {
    @ManyToOne 
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude @ToString.Exclude
    @JoinColumn(name="invoice_id", nullable = false)
    private Invoice invoice;
```

Comment: Thanks @Oleksandr, you save my day. The problem is fix after implementing the changes you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much for the question as well as solution.

Comment: Adding @data will ignore Lazy loading.